# Pygame vertical collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I have a code which make the player move in two dimensions, with no gravity (like Isaac or World Hardest Game). The problem are the collisions with the tiles (celle) in the map:

```
def collisions(self):
    player = self.player.sprite
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.x < 0:
                player.rect.left = cell.rect.right
            elif player.direction.x > 0:
                player.rect.right = cell.rect.left
                
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.y < 0:
                player.rect.top = cell.rect.bottom
            elif player.direction.y > 0:
                player.rect.bottom = cell.rect.top
```

If the player collide moving only in x or only in y it just work, but when it's moving vertically it teleports on the other side. This happens because when it collides in a y side, if it moves in x too the x collisions algorythm triggers. So I tried using a bool to check the x or y collisions:

```
def collisions(self):
    global collx, colly
    player = self.player.sprite
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.x < 0 and colly == False:
                player.rect.left = cell.rect.right
                collx=True
            elif player.direction.x > 0 and colly == False:
                player.rect.right = cell.rect.left
                collx=True
            else:
                collx=False
                
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.y < 0:
                colly=True
                player.rect.top = cell.rect.bottom
            elif player.direction.y > 0:
                colly=True
                player.rect.bottom = cell.rect.top
            else:
                colly=False
```

It works better, but the False condition doesn't occur correctly, I think it's because the code is inside of a for loop, but I don't really know what to do. The code is just too long and contains images so I didn't post it.

movement function in Player class:

```
    def movement(self):
        key_input=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_input[pygame.K_a] or key_input[pygame.K_d]:
            if key_input[pygame.K_a]:
                self.direction.x = -1
                if key_input[pygame.K_w] or key_input[pygame.K_s]:
                    self.rect.x += -self.velx_diag
                else:
                    self.rect.x += -self.velx
            if key_input[pygame.K_d]:
                self.direction.x = 1
                if key_input[pygame.K_w] or key_input[pygame.K_s]:
                    self.rect.x += self.velx_diag
                else:
                    self.rect.x += self.velx
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

        if key_input[pygame.K_w] or key_input[pygame.K_s]:
            if key_input[pygame.K_w]:
                self.direction.y = -1
                if key_input[pygame.K_a] or key_input[pygame.K_d]:
                    self.rect.y += -self.vely_diag
                else:
                    self.rect.y += -self.vely
            if key_input[pygame.K_s]:
                self.direction.y = 1
                if key_input[pygame.K_a] or key_input[pygame.K_d]:
                    self.rect.y += self.vely_diag
                else:
                    self.rect.y += self.vely
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0
```

Comment: There's no need for multiple loops here.  Combine these into one, get rid of the `collx` and `colly` edge cases, and change your `elif`s to simple `if`s so multiple checks can happen.

Comment: @0x5453 doesn't fix the problem, it's just the same of the first code

Comment: could you please post the part where you move the player?

Comment: @Kesslwovv Posted it :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way i know to handle 2d collision is to move the player on one axis, check for collision and then move the player on the other axis:

```
def collision_x(self):
    player = self.player.sprite
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.x < 0:
                player.rect.left = cell.rect.right
            elif player.direction.x > 0:
                player.rect.right = cell.rect.left

# make two different methods for x and y collision.
def collision_y(self):
    for cell in self.celle.sprites():
        if cell.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            if player.direction.y < 0:
                player.rect.top = cell.rect.bottom
            elif player.direction.y > 0:
                player.rect.bottom = cell.rect.top
```

and then in the movement method you need to call those separate:
also your movement function looked a bit messy to me, so I cleaned it up a little bit (if you don't like it, you can use your function too, it works just fine.)

```
    def movement(self):
        key_input=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up = key_input[pygame.K_w]
        down = key_input[pygame.K_s]
        left = key_input[pygame.K_a]
        right = key_input[pygame.K_d]
        y_move = up or down
        x_move = left or right
        if left:
            self.direction.x = -1
            if up or down:
                self.rect.x += -self.velx_diag
            else:
                self.rect.x += -self.velx
        elif right:
                self.direction.x = 1
                if up or down:
                    self.rect.x += self.velx_diag
                else:
                    self.rect.x += self.velx
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

        # this is the important part
        # check the x collision first
        self.collision_x()

        if up:
            self.direction.y = -1
            if left or right:
                self.rect.y += -self.vely_diag
            else:
                self.rect.y += -self.vely
        elif down:
            self.direction.y = 1
            if left or right:
                self.rect.y += self.vely_diag
            else:
                self.rect.y += self.vely
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0

        # now check for the y collision
        self.collision_y()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to change something because movement function was in another class, in another file. basically i divided movementx and movementy and in the collisions file i called:
       `player.movementx()
        self.collision_x()
        player.movementy()
        self.collision_y()`

Comment: Great! glad that i could help